# Colab error: cannot import name 'pix2pixHD_model' from 'pix2pixHD' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using Colab and I am trying to code a Pix2Pix gan.
here is my code:

```
 ! git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD
 ! pip install dominate
```

after this Code block it say this :

```
fatal: destination path 'pix2pixHD' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: dominate in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.6.0)
```

Then I have this :

```
 ! cd pix2pixHD/
 ! python3 setup.py install
 import pix2pixHD
 from pix2pixHD import pix2pixHD_model
 gan_model = pix2pixHD.pix2pixHD_model()
 gan_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
 gan_model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, callbacks=[pix2pixHD.save_weights_callback(gan_model, every=10)])
```

but I am getting this error :

```
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-6ae9c67e59ac> in <module>()
  2 get_ipython().system(' python3 setup.py install')
  3 import pix2pixHD
----> 4 from pix2pixHD import pix2pixHD_model
  5 gan_model = pix2pixHD.pix2pixHD_model()
  6 gan_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

ImportError: cannot import name 'pix2pixHD_model' from 'pix2pixHD' (unknown location)
```

So then I tried this:

```
 %cd pix2pixHD
 ! python3 setup.py install
 import pix2pixHD
 from pix2pixHD import pix2pixHD_model
 gan_model = pix2pixHD.pix2pixHD_model()
 gan_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
 gan_model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, callbacks=[pix2pixHD.save_weights_callback(gan_model, every=10)])
```

but then I got this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pix2pixHD'
/content/pix2pixHD
python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-50-ef300b041421> in <module>()
  2 get_ipython().system(' python3 setup.py install')
  3 import pix2pixHD
 ----> 4 from pix2pixHD import pix2pixHD_model
  5 gan_model = pix2pixHD.pix2pixHD_model()
  6 gan_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

ImportError: cannot import name 'pix2pixHD_model' from 'pix2pixHD' (unknown location)
```

but I can see it right here:
[Picture of my Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxrT9.png)

So I am not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**1. fatal: destination path 'pix2pixHD' already exists ...**

you are trying to clone the repo again, just check if it already exists

**2. ! python3 setup.py install**

This is not a library you have to install. You can directly use `train.py` and `test.py` script once you have all the requirements([getting-started](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD#getting-started)) ready

**3.  from models.pix2pixHD import Pix2PixHDModel**

If you want to import pix2pixmodel,import it like this

```
from models.pix2pixHD_model import Pix2PixHDModel
```

**4. gan_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')**

You cannot start training this way.
Easier way is to use `train.py`. You can find command line arguments defined in `options` directory.

Please go through [readme](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD) once

Comment: I tried  from pix2pixHD import Pix2PixHDModel  but I still  got an  error.  how to access the  pix2pix model?

Comment: my bad, the file name is from `pix2pixHD_model.py` not `pix2pixHD` . You need to call it like this `from models.pix2pixHD_model import Pix2PixHDModel`. editing the same in answer